# A function still fires even if an "if statement" fails

Tags: python, gpio

I have this simple script that listens for a button push and then sends a json trigger to a post request on my server.

If I run this script right now it prints "failed, failed...." over and over, as it should. If I press the button it prints "Black button pressed", and fires the relay, cool.

So why, and bare with me here, even if the button is not pressed it is still firing the sendToServer(json_data) function every half second? And it doesn't print "Black button pressed" and it doesn't actually swap the relays back in forth. My server gets a log in the database every half second: 1,0,1,0,1.....

Its really messing with my head right now. It should only fire a post to the server when the button is pressed like it does when it prints the message.

Thanks in advance

```
pump = 5

def sendToServer(json_data):
    requests.post('https://example.com/gateway/', data = json_data)

count_black = 0
prev_inp_black = 1

def BlackButton(PinNr):
    global prev_inp_black
    global count_black
    
    inp = MCP.input(PinNr)
    if ((not prev_inp_black) and inp):
        count = count_black + 1
        print("Black button pressed")
        current_pump = MCP.input(pump)
        if current_pump == 0:
            MCP.output(pump, 1)
            json_data = { 
                'trigger' : 1
                }
        else:
            MCP.output(pump, 0)
            json_data = { 
                'trigger' : 0
                }
        sendToServer(json_data)
    else:
        print("failed")
    prev_inp_black = inp
    time.sleep(.5)

while True:
    BlackButton(0)
```

Comment: Did you try checking the value returned by `MCP.input(PinNr)` each time the function is called? Is it as you expect? "My server gets a log in the database every half second: 1,0,1,0,1....." Are you **certain** that the requests are caused by **this** part of the code? Notice in particular: you say that you are receiving requests every *half* second, but this code clearly says `time.sleep(1)` at the end of the function.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. In particular, what is `MCP`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sorry, I change it from .5 to 1 on the sleep. I just changed it to every 5 seconds and i get a log in my server every 5 seconds. If I kill the script, it stops sending. For your other question, yes the input stays constant until I press the button, then it swaps from 1 to 0 or vice versa.

Comment: You can always make your function print a stack trace when it's called, so you can see where it's being called from.

Comment: BTW, consider making `BackButton` into a class so you can change your globals to be member variables instead.